# What's better in JAX-RS/Jersey - using a containerResponseFilter or a MessageBodyWriter Provider?

Tags: jaxb, jersey, odata, jax-rs

I'm working on an API using Jersey Server. I have a common root element defined in a bean that I currently wrap around the response from the resource (another bean) using a container response filter. It works great.

It basically returns this:

```
<transaction>
   <status>Good</status>
   <id>1</id>
   ....
</transaction>
```

So it basically wraps the transaction element and status element around the bean returned from the resource, which is annotated with javax.xml binding annotations.

We're looking at implementing the OData format, which provide an Atom style XML, and JSON. Both are in a different format really. So if the media type requested to be returned is application/xml, the filter works as it does now. If the requested media type is application/atom+xml, it needs to return an atom styled xml document.

```
<feed xlmns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
  <title>resource name</title>
  .....
</feed>
```

If the requested media type is application/JSON it needs to return the JSON format of OData which is something like this:

```
"d" : {
  "results" : [
  {
    "__metadata": { 
      "uri" : "http://www.url.com/api/resource" 
    },
    "title" : "reource name",
    ....
  ]}
}
```

I've found online documentation and examples in regards to setting up providers implementing the MessageBodyWriter. I could have one provider for each type. So the produces annotation would have the apporriate media type and the isWriteable method would also check on the appropriate type. Then the writeTo method could alter the format of the bean returned from the resource, and wrap the correct format around it. But is a unique provider like that really the intent and is that the best way to achieve these three possible returns?

I was also thinking of just adding to the container response filter class I already have to check the media type being returned and formatting it accordingly that way, but I worry the filter may get to be "to big", in that it is doing too much for a filter, not sure if that's really a concern.

I could also just handle building the bean up and formatting it accordingly in each resource method, but it would save time to do it once, or three times uniquely, and have that applied to every bean returned.

Which direction is better? Is there another option that may be even better than these two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing your own MessageBodyWriter is definitely the right way to go, given you have a specific media type associated with the format and you want to handle the serialization of all the requests for such media type the same way.

Comment: That's what I was thinking to - makes sense. Currently in the filter I have a set annotated beans. In the writeTo method I am dealing with streams, so I wouldn't necessarily set beans, but just add to the stream - I was concerned about that. Am I mistaken? Can I have the same functionality in my MessageBodyWriter as I have in my filter just stream it on the way out?